# qiskit bind to parameter fails to detect value is real

Tags: qiskit, qiskit-runtime

I have a complex QuantumCircuit with some parameters, and I use `.bind_parameter({param: value, ....})` to evaluate the parameters to some value. I worked fine for a very long number of runs (probably thousands of them) and today suddenly I am getting messages that the parameters are not real. Inspecting with the debugger shows that the values I am passing are real, but for some reasons it does not get detected as such. Any suggestions on what is going wrong?

[image][image]

Comment: What version of Qiskit do you have?

Comment: This seems like a Qiskit specific issue, it would be better to open an issue there instead of here: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues

Comment: Issue is open here: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/9663